# AWS ELB - how to attach the latest/newest snapshot automatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, scripting, elastic-beanstalk

I'm really new to AWS ELB and I'm reading about how to automatically mount an EBS volume from a snapshot via the ebextensions script.  I've found this post as a reference: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/customize-ephemeral-and-ebs-volumes-in-elastic-beanstalk-environments/

But basically, my question is, how do I set in the option settings to have it automatically pull the latest snapshot id?  Because the snapshots will be updated daily, and I only want to get the latest snapshot without having to edit the ebextensions script each time.

This is what I'm thinking the ebextensions script will be:

```
commands:
  01mkdir:
    command: "mkdir /mnt/ebs_snapshot"
  02mount:
    command: "mount /dev/sdh /mnt/ebs_snapshot"
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
    option_name: BlockDeviceMappings
    value: /dev/sdh=(how to put latest snapshot id?)
```

I also found this post: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/13514/find-the-most-recent-snapshot-for-an-aws-ebs-volume

But not sure how to incorporate that into the ebextensions script file...

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to dynamically specify the block device mappings within the `.ebextensions`.

Instead, you'll need to create your own script to:

1. find the latest snapshot,
2. detach any existing volume from `/dev/sdh`,
3. create a new volume from your snapshot, and finally
4. attach the volume to your instance.

This script you can create/specify within the `files` and `commands` seconds of the `.ebextensions` files.